# Regarding scheduling jobs analysis

Tags: algorithm

I am reading topic on scheduling algorithm analysis:

> suppose we have the four jobs and associated running times shown
>   below. One possible schedule j1, j2, j3, and j4  Because j1 finishes
>   in 15 (time units), j2 in 23, j3 in 26, and j4 in 36, the average
>   completion time is 25. A better schedule, which yields a mean
>   completion time of 17.75, is j3, j2, j4 and j1.
>
> Job  Time
>
> ---
>
> j1    15
>
> j2     8
>
> j3     3
>
> j4    10

My question how author calculated average completion time i.e., how we got 25 and 17.75 in above text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jobs run serially (one at a time).

Hence with order `j1-j2-j3-j4`, `j1` finishes at `15`, `j2` finishes at `15+8=23`, `j3` finishes at `15+8+3=26` and `j4` finishes at `15+8+3+10=36`. They then average `15`, `23`, `26` and `36` to get `25` using your standard `sum/count` formula:

```
  (15 + 23 + 26 + 36) / 4
=         100         / 4
=                25
```

In other words, the completion time they're talking about is not how long a job took from when it started but how long it took from the start of the *first* job (ie, a point in time rather than a duration). I'm not sure how *useful* such a metric is, but that's what they're doing, based on the figures.

With order `j3-j2-j4-j1`, `j3` finishes at `3`, `j2` finishes at `3+8=11`, `j4` finishes at `3+8+10=21` and `j1` finishes at `3+8+10+15=36`. The average of that (`3`, `11`, `21` and `36`) is `17.75`.

The optimum (lowest) solution for the average finishing time is to do the jobs in order of increasing duration.

That's because the last job in a set of four will always finish at the same time, regardless of order (`36` in this case).

So, in order to reduce the average finishing point, the finishing points of the other three jobs should be as low as possible.

And, the same rule that applies to four jobs also applies to three jobs (once the longest-running `j1` is taken out of the mix). Then two jobs, once you've removed `j4`.

Once you've removed three jobs, the only one standing is the one you should choose (of course).

Comment: sorry  i didn't get how do we got 25 as average time?

Comment: @venkysmarty: `(15+23+26+36)/4 = 100/4 = 25`. In other words they're averaging the completion "points in time". I've fleshed out the answer to hopefully make that clearer.